# "Лента орнамента служит нам навигацией"?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Двухцветная лента орнамента вновь служит нам навигацией, уточняет
>   смысл – она отделяет нижний фриз рассказа от сцены, что разыгрывается
>   не на земле…

Что, поменять на путеводную звезду?

Ваши предложения!

Comment: ...для навигации? Хотя, уместно ли тут слово навигация? Может, лента помогает сориентироваться? Служит ориентиром?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Навигация бывает морская, сухопутная и даже... *смысловая*:

https://grebennikon.ru/article-h7g6.html

Вот с её помощью и можно попытаться развесить желанную клюкву:

> Двухцветная лента орнамента *и здесь* служит нам *для смысловой навигации* –
>   ...